# "If $f: X \to Y$ and $\dim(X) =\dim(Y)$, then $f(X)$ is open in $Y$" Is this a general fact?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading an article and I come to a statement that I am not sure if it is a general fact. In one line, the article says that $f:X \to Y$ where $\dim(X) = \dim(Y)$, so $f(X)$ is open in $Y$. Of course, there are some more properties in $f,X$ and $Y$ ($X,Y$ are open and connected, $f$ is differentiable). However, it seems to me that the author does not need any of them at all, because his statement is basically alone. I am wondering if this is a result in topology, which I am not very good at. So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $\dim X$?

Comment: $dim(X)$ means the dimension of $X$, which is some positive integer $n$.

Comment: It is not true in general, take the constant function.

Comment: And what is the dimension of $X$?

Comment: Well, in fact $f$ is injective, so constant function is certainly out of picture. Does that change anything? And dimension of $X$ is not given, just not infinite.

Comment: @BMYoon Please, put all the hypotheses and the context on the question. Most likely $X,Y$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the same $n$ (or manifolds) and $\dim$ means the dimension of the Euclidean space they are in (resp. dimension as a manifold), and also most likely $f$ is injective. This is then a result called [Invariance of Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: @BMYoon As it is, we don't know what is $X$ or $Y$, what is "$\dim(X)$", the hypotheses on $f$ etc.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't put every knowledge about $f,X,Y$ here, because I don't want my question to look like a HW problem, and in fact the paper includes so much properties about them that I don't want to divert attention from the dimension condition. Anyway, thank you, Invariance of Domain is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a constant function, then $f(X)$ is a singleton. And in general, singletons are not open sets.